# Strange react-router v4 behavior with parent paths

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

**Backstory:** 
I'm building this simple application and i want to make it have pretty urls with `react-router v4`.

I've got 3 main components: `{Home}`, `{List}`, `{Hotel}`:

`{Home}` Component - a simple component where i can select `country`, `datefrom` and `dateto` and route myself to `{List}`.

Current path example: http://url.com/

`{List}` Component - A heavy component with a cards full of hotels with links to /hotel/ route.

Current path example: http://url.com/list/country/?datefrom=2019-01-01?dateto=2020-01-01

`{Hotel}` Component - Most far part of the app, heavy component with hotel information and list of prices split by day.

Current path example: http://url.com/hotel/country/hotel-name/?datefrom=2019-01-01?dateto=2020-01-01

**The problem:** What i'm trying to do is replace `/list/` and use `/hotels/` for a `{List}` component, so i would have somewhat of a hierarchy in url structure.

But once i tried to change `/list/` -> `/hotels/` for a `{List}` component route, my whole app breaks and i'm greeted with lots and lots of errors from `{Hotel}` component, this happens when i try to route myself from `{Home}` component to `{List}`.

**What i've tried:** i've tried to use `<Switch>` component, it makes `{Home}` -> `{List}` route work, but when i try to route myself any further to a `{Hotel}` component, it actualy render at the bottom of the page and doesn't replace my `{List}`

Here's my app.js file that gives me strange behavior...

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./Home";
import List from "./List";
import Hotel from "./Hotel";

import './styles/app.scss';

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="app">
          <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
          <Route path="/hotels/:selectedCountry/:datefrom?:dateto?" component={List} />
          <Route path="/hotels/:selectedCountry/:selectedHotel:datefrom?:dateto?" component={Hotel} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Hotel` and `List` refer to the same resource, a hotel, but `Hotel` refers to a single hotel, i.e. is singular, while `List` refers to an index of hotels, i.e is plural. Usually, routing is done by having a singular and a plural route.

Example taken from GitHub:
URL of a list of commits: https://github.com/facebook/react/commits
URL of a single commit: https://github.com/facebook/react/commit/ec6691a6

In your case it would be:

```
<Route path="/hotels/your-search-params here" component={List} />
<Route path="/hotels/:hotelId:" component={Hotel} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route definition is not correct.

e.g. take a look at the route path `/hotels/:country/:id/:fromDate/:toDate`, so a url like this `/hotels/usa/123/2019-01-01/2019-12-30` will map correctly to route params and you can access these values in your component like `this.props.match.params.id` etc. but if you want to take the query params approach then you need to add `&` sign in between two params like `/hotels?country=usa&id=123&fromDate=2019-01-01&toDate=2019-12-30` and then you will access it from `window.location.href` and parse the query parameters or use npm package like `query-params` to parse. In this scenario your Route path will be just `/hotels`